# Pandas: Access row number

Tags: python, pandas

Such a simple question to which I can't find an answer:

In `Pandas`, how do I access the row number of the index?

The context is

```
def func(row):
    print row.col1,
    # print row.index_value <--- What should go here?
    return

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.name` attribute:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')}).set_index('A')

print (df)
   B  C  D  E  F
A               
a  4  7  1  5  a
b  5  8  3  3  a
c  4  9  5  6  a
d  5  4  7  9  b
e  5  2  1  2  b
f  4  3  0  4  b

def func(row):
    print (row.name)
    return

a
b
c
d
e
f

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a preference over row.name and row.Index?

Comment: it seems where I've used `.Index` to return the row index I'm using in conjunction with `.itertuples()`.

Comment: Perfect - THANK YOU!

Comment: the apply method takes row by row into the function, a row is a series that has the columns as indexes, so .name is the attribute to take for row index

Answer (score 0):

Close! To access the index for a row it is simply:

```
row.Index
```

Sorry, this is to be used when iterating through the rows of the dataframe using `.itertuples()`. Please see Jezrael's answer.

Comment: No, it is use for itertuples

Comment: @JohnyVaknin - the [suggested code](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) in Pandas is with it as `.Index`!

Comment: @Nordle - the [index attribute of a series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.index.html#pandas.Series.index) is .index, unlike creating a pure [Index class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) , [pep8 is the stuff](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: @JohnyVaknin - gotcha, thanks for the lesson! I know it's creating a class as opposed to accessing an attribute of a class, but as the result it's giving me works all the same I just stuck with it haha.